# Wordpress - Sort post of one category alphabetically

Tags: wordpress, sorting, categories, posts

I'm at the end, I'm not even sure if I'm doing the right thing.
I added the current code to the function.php, I need to change the order for one specific category. So I mean to say the category "internal-communication" to display posts by date added or alphabetically, but only one, I set a different global setting for the others.
Can anyone help me? Thank you.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 5,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => 'interni-sdeleni',
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'ASC',
    'include'          => 'interni-sdeleni',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => 'interni-sdeleni',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'   => '',
    'post_parent'      => '',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true );

$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: You could use `pre_get_posts` for that. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code -

```
$args = array(
'posts_per_page'   => 5,
'offset'           => 0,
'category'         => 'interni-sdeleni',
'orderby'          => 'name',
'order'            => 'ASC',
'include'          => 'interni-sdeleni',
'exclude'          => '',
'meta_key'         => '',
'meta_value'       => 'interni-sdeleni',
'post_type'        => 'post',
'post_mime_type'   => '',
'post_parent'      => '',
'post_status'      => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true );
```

$posts_array = get_posts( $args );

Comment: Old code work for all categories, but "include" do nothing

I need implement this but right:

    'include'          => 'interni-sdeleni',